# Pointer to pointer to std::vector as an output argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I put a pointer to pointer to vector as an output argument in a function and I don't know if that is the best practice:

`Status Interface::method(const std::vector<int>** outVec);`

I'm writing an API for a class where each function returns a status.
For that I need to return the result through the function arguments.
I don't want to use an std::vector reference since that would require from the user to provide an empty vector, rather than me creating the vector an providing it.
Is there a cleaner approach for this?

Comment: Normally you almost never need a pointer to a container. And a pointer to a pointer? Why? Why is it a problem for the caller to create the vector object, and pass a reference to it?

Comment: The flexibility of output arguments hardly ever outweighs their setbacks. For a return value the API is obvious; it is an output. For an output argument this is _not_ obvious from the API; it may be an input/output situation. Also, one has to study the documentation (or even implementation) to figure out if the output argument stays unmodified in case of a failure. That’s _bad_ for readability. The answer below gives one good option, but you may also want to consider e.g. [`absl::StatusOr`](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/status). Or just use exceptions. This is exactly what they are for.

Comment: If you're worried about copying the internals of the vector – that's not an issue any more since C++11, we have move semantics now, and even greater, we have guaranteed copy elision since C++17. So no need to worry about any overhead on returning vectors.

Comment: If your plan is that this function creates the vector dynamically with `new`, and the caller is then responsible for `delete`ing it, that's not "cleaner" than just passing a vector that the caller can manage in any way they like.

Comment: Also, the setup is prone to memory leaks. Use a `std::vector<int>&` instead (if it _must_ be an output argument). `std::vector<int>**` raises too many open questions: What should happen if `outVec == nullptr`? (Nothing?) What should happen if `*outVec != nullptr`? (A deallocation attempt? A reuse attempt?) Using `std::vector<int>&` answers most of these questions: It should not hold a `nullptr` (as that would be undefined behavior). The vector is always present and valid. The only thing left to specify is whether it is replaced or `push_back()`ed. But all memory ownership concerns are gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is to return the vector from the function.

```
std::pair<Status,std::vector<int>> method();
```

or

```
struct MethodResult {
     Status status;
     std::vector<int> vect;
};
MethodResult method();
```

or similar.

You are right that using a reference out parameter has downsides, but your solution is even worse. The caller still has to provide the pointer to be passed to the function. And then they face the issue of what to do with the vector when its not needed anymore. Was it dynamically allocated? How? Why? Raw pointers should not be used to own a resource and not to transfer ownership. There is no reason to open this can of worms when a `std::vector` is already managing the memory for your and you can simply return it from the function.

See also [C++ Core Guidelines F20: For “out” output values, prefer return values to output parameters](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out)

Comment: And if for some reason you really need a dynamically allocated vector (hint: you probably don't) you can return `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'd prefer the unique pointer over the shared one in first place – it comes with less overhead ('don't pay for what you don't need' principle) – unless, of course, we know in advance that we need to share the object…

Comment: I don't dynamically allocate the vector, its a field in the class, I just return a pointer to it. I agree that for safe dynamic allocations I should use C++ destructor mechanics, I always watch out for that. I'm just not too sure about accessing vector through pointers.

Comment: The problem with what you suggested is the inconsistency of using different Status structs for different return values. I want to have one consistent return value of Status

Comment: @Daniel "I'm just not too sure about accessing vector through pointers"  simply do not use pointers. You dont need them here. If you want to return a reference to a vector that is member of some object then return a reference

Comment: @Daniel you can return `std::pair<Status, some_other_type>` where `some_other_type`is what the method returns, then all methods consistently return a `std::pair` where `first` is the `Status`. Anyhow, when there are such constraints you should mention them in the question.